# Blog search just returns to front page (not search results!)

Tags: search

When I enter in a search query in my blog's search box, it simply returns to my blog's front page with URL http://www.mywebpage.com/?s+id%3D=mysearchquery. Here's my search box code:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
  <?php 
    echo "<!--[if !IE]> --><input type='text' name='s id='s' class='blog_search_field' placeholder='Search' value=''/><!--<![endif]-->";
    echo "<!--[if IE]><input type='text' name='s id='s' class='blog_search_field' value='Search' /><![endif]-->";
  ?>    
</form>
```

The front page is a static page at www.mywebpage.com, and then the blog index page is at www.mywebpage.com/?page_id=7.  Any pointers would be terrific. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Make a `search.php` like [TwentyFifteen](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyfifteen/1.0/search.php) in your theme and you may see the search result.

Comment: If blog index page isn't at the root why would URL point there? How exactly is your front/home is set up?

Comment: Hi @Rarst, thanks for the comment. The front page was selected under "Settings->Reading->Front page displays" to be a static page. The blog index page is at www.mywebpage.com/?page_id=7, and it's a homemade template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is a syntax error: `name='s` should be `name='s'`.

Comment: Gald to help ;)